# Power BI Date Calculated Indicator

Tags: dax

Fairly new to DAX so I'm hoping some one can point out where I am going wrong with this code which to check and see if a feild falls within a period based on today and display an indicator.

Thanks In Advance

T

My Code:

```
Update Health = IF([Project Modified Date]= NOW() <= (NOW()-10),'Projects'.[PWA URL] & "/_layouts/15/inc/PWA/images/cf_6p.png",IF([Project Modified Date]=NOW() <= (NOW()-5),'Projects'.[PWA URL] & "/_layouts/15/inc/PWA/images/cf_1p.png",IF([Project Modified Date]=NOW() <= (NOW()-1),'Projects'.[PWA URL] & "/_layouts/15/inc/PWA/images/cf_2p.png",'Projects'.[PWA URL] & "/_layouts/15/inc/PWA/images/cf_11p.png")))
```

MS Code The Above Is Based On:

```
Schedule Health = IF([SKPI]="Less than 10% over baseline schedule",[PWA URL] & "/_layouts/15/inc/PWA/images/cf_6p.png",IF([SKPI]="Between 10%-20% over baseline schedule",[PWA URL] & "/_layouts/15/inc/PWA/images/cf_1p.png",IF([SKPI]="At least 20% over baseline schedule",[PWA URL] & "/_layouts/15/inc/PWA/images/cf_2p.png",[PWA URL] & "/_layouts/15/inc/PWA/images/cf_11p.png")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed a new column and not a new measure.

T